# How to properly apply the transformations of a ModelInstance in libGDX?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx

I am writing my first 3D libGDX game, and I am stuck with the following scenario:
I have a scene, loaded from a `g3db` file. The `ModelInstance` I am trying to transform is controlled by a separate class. In its `move()` method I am currently trying to rotate the `ModelInstance` around its own Y coordinate. The code for that is the following:

```
Vector3 position = model.calculateBoundingBox(new BoundingBox()).getCenter();
    model.transform.translate(-position.x, 0f, -position.z);
    model.transform.rotate(Vector3.Y, (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(adjacent/hypotenuse))));
    model.transform.translate(position.x, 0f, position.z);
    model.calculateTransforms();
```

FYI, `adjacent` and `hypotenuse` are used to find the cosine of the angle between the Y center of the screen and the line between the center of the screen and the point touched.

What I am trying to do with this code is to translate `model` (the `ModelInstance`) to the center of the coordinate system, rotate it around world's Y and translate it back to where it originally was. Instead, `model` rotates around world's Y with the original offset from the center. How do I apply the desired transformation properly?

Comment: Then how do I perform the rotation?